# how to render dropdown from ajax

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, drop-down-menu

My json response is like this (as per firebug)

```
[
{
    "value": 1,
    "text": "Bill_Process_1",
    "selected": false,
    "imageSrc": "image.jpg",
    "description": "Bill_Process_1"
},
{
    "value": 2,
    "text": "Bill_Process_2",
    "selected": false,
    "imageSrc": "image.jpg",
    "description": "Bill_Process_2"
},
{
    "value": 3,
    "text": "Bill_Process_3",
    "selected": false,
    "imageSrc": "image.jpg",
    "description": "Bill_Process_3"
},
{
    "value": 4,
    "text": "Bill_Process_4",
    "selected": false,
    "imageSrc": "image.jpg",
    "description": "Bill_Process_4"
},
{
    "value": 5,
    "text": "Bill_Process_5",
    "selected": false,
    "imageSrc": "image.jpg",
    "description": "Bill_Process_5"
}
```

]

Please help me to complete this code.its just show empty drop down.
I'm confused with how to render it to here..

```
        <div id="myDropdown"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonurl = 'dropDown.html';
    $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: jsonurl,
          data: {},
          success:function(data){
                 var options = $("#myDropdown");
                 $.each(data, function () {
                     alert(data);
                     options.append($("<option />").val(this.value).text(this.text));                        
                 });
             },
          error:function(){             
          }
        });     

    $('#myDropdown').ddslick({
        data : jsonurl,
        width : 300,
        selectText : "Select the bill process",
        imagePosition : "right",
        onSelected : function(selectedData) {
            //callback function: do something with selectedData;
        }
    });
</script>
```

I used spring @ResponseBody to return this json array.

I used ddslick for my drop down.here shows it is

[ddslick drop down by jquery code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO3im.jpg)

Now my out put like this.its not data loaded to div as drop down and on webpage it shows as list one by one

[image: My output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with something like this:

```
 success:function(data){
     var options = $("#myDropdown");
     $.each(data, function () {
         options.append($("<option />").val(this.value).text(this.text));
     });
 },
```

in your AJAX success handler to solve the problem of drop-down being empty. I'm not too sure what you'd like to achieve on select.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsonurl = 'dropDown.html';
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: jsonurl,
      data: {},
      success:function(myData){
          $('#myDropdown').ddslick({
               data : myData,
               width : 300,
               selectText : "Select the bill process",
               imagePosition : "right",
               onSelected : function(selectedData) {
                //callback function: do something with selectedData;
               }
          });
      },
      error:function(){             
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: > rajesh kakawat : 
Thanks you so much..you saved my lot of time..
now its working perfectly.where is my wrong point ?

Comment: I have passed actually data from response to ddslick.whereas you have been adding to your div.By your code ,your ajax was fired and your ddslick was initialize before ajax response was completed so your ddslick was empty.